# Pivoting wide to long conditionally for certain columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, pivot-table

I'm working with a dataset of author collaborations. Here's a subset of five articles with article ID, corresponding author (RP), corresponding author's country (Country), author full names (AF_1:AF_3), and author short names (AU_1:AU_3):

```
articles <- structure(list(
ArtID = 1:5,
RP = c("DE GARRIDO, L","CURSEU, PL","HENIKE, T","DI VINCENZO, F","OMIGIE, D"),
Country = c("spain", "romania", "germany", "italy", NA),
AF_1 = c("DE GARRIDO, LUIS","CURSEU, PETRU L.","STIELER, MAXIMILIAN","DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO","OMIGIE, DIANA"),
AF_2 = c(NA,"SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L.","HENIKE, TASSILO","IACOPINO, VALENTINA","RICCI, JESSICA"),
AF_3 = c(NA, "FODOR, OANA C.", NA, NA, NA),
AU_1 = c("DE GARRIDO L", "CURSEU PL", "STIELER M","DI VINCENZO F", "OMIGIE D"),
AU_2 = c(NA, "SCHRUIJER SGL", "HENIKE T","IACOPINO V", "RICCI J"),
AU_3 = c(NA, "FODOR OC", NA, NA, NA)),
row.names = c(NA,-5L),class = c("data.frame"))

> articles
  ArtID             RP Country                AF_1                    AF_2           AF_3          AU_1          AU_2     AU_3
1     1  DE GARRIDO, L   spain    DE GARRIDO, LUIS                    <NA>           <NA>  DE GARRIDO L          <NA>     <NA>
2     2     CURSEU, PL romania    CURSEU, PETRU L. SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L. FODOR, OANA C.     CURSEU PL SCHRUIJER SGL FODOR OC
3     3      HENIKE, T germany STIELER, MAXIMILIAN         HENIKE, TASSILO           <NA>     STIELER M      HENIKE T     <NA>
4     4 DI VINCENZO, F   italy DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO     IACOPINO, VALENTINA           <NA> DI VINCENZO F    IACOPINO V     <NA>
5     5      OMIGIE, D    <NA>       OMIGIE, DIANA          RICCI, JESSICA           <NA>      OMIGIE D       RICCI J     <NA>
```

When pivoting the data from wide (articles) to long (authors), it automatically copies other column values for all authors (i.e., country). pivot_longer code and data:

```
authors <- articles %>% pivot_longer(cols=starts_with(c("AF","AU")),names_to=c(".value","ArtAthID"),names_sep="_",values_drop_na=T)

> authors
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   ArtID RP             Country ArtAthID AF                      AU           
   <int> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>        
 1     1 DE GARRIDO, L  spain   1        DE GARRIDO, LUIS        DE GARRIDO L 
 2     2 CURSEU, PL     romania 1        CURSEU, PETRU L.        CURSEU PL    
 3     2 CURSEU, PL     romania 2        SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L. SCHRUIJER SGL
 4     2 CURSEU, PL     romania 3        FODOR, OANA C.          FODOR OC     
 5     3 HENIKE, T      germany 1        STIELER, MAXIMILIAN     STIELER M    
 6     3 HENIKE, T      germany 2        HENIKE, TASSILO         HENIKE T     
 7     4 DI VINCENZO, F italy   1        DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO     DI VINCENZO F
 8     4 DI VINCENZO, F italy   2        IACOPINO, VALENTINA     IACOPINO V   
 9     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      1        OMIGIE, DIANA           OMIGIE D     
10     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      2        RICCI, JESSICA          RICCI J
```

However, when pivoting, I want some columns (Country, Uni, Email) to stay with the corresponding author and be NA for the other authors. For example, Country should look like this:

```
> authors
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   ArtID RP             Country ArtAthID AF                      AU           
   <int> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>        
 1     1 DE GARRIDO, L  spain   1        DE GARRIDO, LUIS        DE GARRIDO L 
 2     2 CURSEU, PL     romania 1        CURSEU, PETRU L.        CURSEU PL    
 3     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      2        SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L. SCHRUIJER SGL
 4     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      3        FODOR, OANA C.          FODOR OC     
 5     3 HENIKE, T      NA      1        STIELER, MAXIMILIAN     STIELER M    
 6     3 HENIKE, T      germany 2        HENIKE, TASSILO         HENIKE T     
 7     4 DI VINCENZO, F italy   1        DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO     DI VINCENZO F
 8     4 DI VINCENZO, F NA      2        IACOPINO, VALENTINA     IACOPINO V   
 9     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      1        OMIGIE, DIANA           OMIGIE D     
10     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      2        RICCI, JESSICA          RICCI J
```

I've tried a few things (trying to use matching between RP and AU), but am hitting a wall. Any suggestions for how to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the pivot is working as designed, as it is keeping the data associated with all authors. What you're asking to do is de-duplicate `Country` (and perhaps others) within a particular `ArtID`.

Try this:

```r
authors %>%
  group_by(ArtID) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Country), ~ replace(., duplicated(.), .[NA][1]))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#    ArtID RP             Country ArtAthID AF                      AU           
#    <int> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>        
#  1     1 DE GARRIDO, L  spain   1        DE GARRIDO, LUIS        DE GARRIDO L 
#  2     2 CURSEU, PL     romania 1        CURSEU, PETRU L.        CURSEU PL    
#  3     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      2        SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L. SCHRUIJER SGL
#  4     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      3        FODOR, OANA C.          FODOR OC     
#  5     3 HENIKE, T      germany 1        STIELER, MAXIMILIAN     STIELER M    
#  6     3 HENIKE, T      NA      2        HENIKE, TASSILO         HENIKE T     
#  7     4 DI VINCENZO, F italy   1        DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO     DI VINCENZO F
#  8     4 DI VINCENZO, F NA      2        IACOPINO, VALENTINA     IACOPINO V   
#  9     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      1        OMIGIE, DIANA           OMIGIE D     
# 10     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      2        RICCI, JESSICA          RICCI J
```

Notes:

- You mentioned doing the same for `Uni` and `Email`, but those columns were not in the original data (which is fine). For this reason, I chose to use `mutate(across(c(Country), ..))` instead of the more conventional `mutate(Country = replace(..))`: include your other columns in that `c(.)` vector, perhaps just `mutate(across(c(Country, Uni, Email), ~ ...))`.
- The `replace` should be clear enough, but the `.[NA][1]` is to make sure that the replacement (of `NA`) is the same *class* of `NA` as the original column. There are at least six different classes of `NA`, and some R tools -- notably many within `dplyr` and `tidyr` -- complain when trying to combine an integer NA (`NA_integer_`) with a logical (`NA`) or string (`NA_character_`) or real/floating-point (`NA_real_`), to name a few. The use of `.[NA]` will always give the correct class. The addition of `[1]` is to get around the fact that `replace(.)` requires the third argument to be the same length as the number of values to replace, not necessarily the same length as the input argument `x`; this same-length is relaxed when *recycling*, so I truncate this to be always length-1.

Your desired output for `ArtID=3` showed the `NA` *before* `"germany"`, which seemed like just a typo in the sample data. If you want it matched (`grepl`) between `RP` and the other fields, then perhaps this works better (though some articles with this example clear out all countries):

```r
authors %>%
  mutate(tmp = mapply(function(x, ...) any(grepl(x, unlist(list(...)))), RP, AF, AU), across(c(Country), ~ if_else(tmp, ., .[NA]))) %>%
  select(-tmp)
# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#    ArtID RP             Country ArtAthID AF                      AU           
#    <int> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>        
#  1     1 DE GARRIDO, L  spain   1        DE GARRIDO, LUIS        DE GARRIDO L 
#  2     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      1        CURSEU, PETRU L.        CURSEU PL    
#  3     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      2        SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L. SCHRUIJER SGL
#  4     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      3        FODOR, OANA C.          FODOR OC     
#  5     3 HENIKE, T      NA      1        STIELER, MAXIMILIAN     STIELER M    
#  6     3 HENIKE, T      germany 2        HENIKE, TASSILO         HENIKE T     
#  7     4 DI VINCENZO, F italy   1        DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO     DI VINCENZO F
#  8     4 DI VINCENZO, F NA      2        IACOPINO, VALENTINA     IACOPINO V   
#  9     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      1        OMIGIE, DIANA           OMIGIE D     
# 10     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      2        RICCI, JESSICA          RICCI J
```

This second method is flawed because of the mismatch in author name formats (`"HENIKE, T" != "HENIKE T"`, for instance). If you can come up with a better way to match `RP` with the other columns, then this may be more to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I apologize if my answer made it sound like pivot_longer isn't doing what it should. Like you said, it's working exactly as designed. I want to "override" the default for a few columns. The output for ArtID=3 is correct in my original post. I want the NA before germany in this case (there are other cases like this as well). I'll remove the commas from RP so that it matches AU.

Comment: I understand. You need to find a way to match `HENIKE, T` with `HENIKE, TASSILO` (grepl, though incomplete) or `HENIKE T`. The real problem is with `CURSEU, PL` where it is a bit more different from the other columns that a simple pattern match is not going to work. Once you work through how to match it correctly, I think the second mechanism should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want within `pivot_longer`, but I think this gives you what you need for one "additional" variable (Which is all you've given us in your test data...)

```
articles %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=starts_with(c("AF","AU")),
    names_to=c(".value","ArtAthID"),
    names_sep="_",
    values_drop_na=T
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Country=ifelse(row_number() == 1, Country, NA)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 × 6
# Groups:   Country [5]
   ArtID RP             Country ArtAthID AF                      AU           
   <int> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>        
 1     1 DE GARRIDO, L  spain   1        DE GARRIDO, LUIS        DE GARRIDO L 
 2     2 CURSEU, PL     romania 1        CURSEU, PETRU L.        CURSEU PL    
 3     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      2        SCHRUIJER, SANDRA G. L. SCHRUIJER SGL
 4     2 CURSEU, PL     NA      3        FODOR, OANA C.          FODOR OC     
 5     3 HENIKE, T      germany 1        STIELER, MAXIMILIAN     STIELER M    
 6     3 HENIKE, T      NA      2        HENIKE, TASSILO         HENIKE T     
 7     4 DI VINCENZO, F italy   1        DI VINCENZO, FAUSTO     DI VINCENZO F
 8     4 DI VINCENZO, F NA      2        IACOPINO, VALENTINA     IACOPINO V   
 9     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      1        OMIGIE, DIANA           OMIGIE D     
10     5 OMIGIE, D      NA      2        RICCI, JESSICA          RICCI J
```

if you need more than one additional variable, add each to the `group_by()` call and then use `across()` in the `mutate()`.  Something like (untested code):

```
...
%>% mutate(
      across(
        c(Country, Uni, Email), 
        function(x) ifelse(row_number() == 1, x, NA)
      )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This doesn't exactly solve my issue because the corresponding author isn't always the first author. However, it still helped me in figuring out a solution!